# Codeigniter Session losing data between pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been having trouble with my site where the session data gets ruined if a string containing something like `\\\'` is added to an array in the session data one page before. I'm trying to figure out ways to fix this.

An Example of what happens:

```
    function testsession(){
        session_start();
        $breakingString['key'] = 'breaking code \\\'';  //Array containing string the that causes the break. It only breaks if in an array.
        $this->session->set_userdata('breakval', $breakingString);
        redirect('admin/testsession2');
    }
    function testsession2(){
        var_dump($this->session->userdata('breakval')); //returns false
        die;
    }
```

Is there any way to stop this bug from happening beyond encoding everything in base64?

Comment: It doesn't return false for me. Can you post your actual code implementation so we can help track down where the issue is? Also if you're using CodeIgniter sessions you don't need `session_start()`. Did you load the Session library with: `$this->load->library('session');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have must to put session_start(); on all pages where you want to have access to data saved in $_SESSION.

[PHP Sessions basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)